# Export query from DB Manager QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have following query:

```
SELECT NOPARC, MAX(LEN),geom_from_wkt(geometry) AS geomd FROM lines group by oznakas
```

And I get following output:

[image]

My goal is to export this to external shp file with georeferenced members, but somehow I cant get geomd column to display geometry.

I tried also similar approach with: Add vector layer > Virtual Layer and using above SQL, but all I get is virtual layer displayed as image:

[image]

How can export SQL query with spatial component ( georeferenced .shp) ?

**EDIT:**

From [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5DfuTWg1OMkYdnPnwU3K6bA9ke-A?e=ZSOxaS), sample *.shp file can be downloaded.
I added `geom` column with `geom_to_wkt( $geometry )` command. Field is added as txt type.
This is what i get as output:
[image]

Hope this clarifies thinks.
Desired output is same, georeferenced shp file with query results.

Comment: I don't have field 'geometry' at all in 'lines' table

Comment: Then you should get an error when selecting `geom_from_wkt(geometry)`? Can you add a screenshot showing your lines table?

Comment: If you don't have geometry field, how the attribute information is displayed using the query? It should throw an error due to you included non existent field.

Comment: I edited original question and added link to sample input.

Comment: Just use plain `geometry` (or an aggregate function like `ST_Collect(geometry) AS geometry`) in the `SELECT` list...no need to transform the internal data type to anything else. Then `Export as...` -> *shapefile*

Comment: @geozelot It works, I get correct output in table, but on map, I still see all lines when i zoom in: https://imgur.com/RqHMOFS .

Comment: Did you try just plain `geometry` instead of `ST_Collect()`? I got the correct geometry output using QGIS 3.18.3